# Can not see the DB query output in python

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm execute a simple mssql query from python.
I can see in the profiler that the query reach the DB.
The query has 1 row of answer.
I fail to see the output in the Python shell

I run the code below

```
import pymssql 
conn = pymssql.connect(host='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase', as_dict=True) 
cur = conn.cursor()  
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe') 
for row in cur:     
    print "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row['id'], row['name'])
```

Pleas advise
Thanks,
Assaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [fetchone()](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/ref_pymssql.php) or fetchall() after execute to get the data from that query.

```
import pymssql 
conn = pymssql.connect(host='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase', as_dict=True) 
cur = conn.cursor()  
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe') 
print cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pymssql  
conn = pymssql.connect(host='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase', as_dict=True)  
cur = conn.cursor()   
users = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe').fetchall()  
conn.close()   

for row in users:     
    print "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row['id'], row['name'])
```

Try assigning the results to something instead of using the cursor.

`cur.execute()` is a function, as such while it does return a value (which you saw), you're not assigning it to anything, so when you go to do the `for` loop, there's nothing to loop over.

If you don't want to store the result, you could do this (rather messy) version:

```
import pymssql  
conn = pymssql.connect(host='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase', as_dict=True)  
cur = conn.cursor() 
sql = 'SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s'

for row in cur.execute(sql, 'John Doe').fetchall():
    print "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row['id'], row['name'])

conn.close()
```

This one does the `for` loop over the result of the `cur.execute()`, but I really advise against this

(Minor addendum: I forgot the fetchall's, I'm so used to putting this in a function. Sorry)